# History logs in Lubuntu Server

Tags: server, lubuntu, dmesg

May someone tell me if the system logs (especially dmesg) are archived somewhere else than /var/logs? In this folder I can find only dmesg from last 6 restarts. I need to look two weeks before to solve a problem.

in /etc/logrotate.conf i could see:

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4
```

How can it be, that on server distro i can not look into logs older than last few restarts, which I have performed in the last two days? Or did I miss something?

I'm using Lubuntu Server 19.10

Comment: Lubuntu is a desktop OS, have you installed `lubuntu-desktop` on your Ubuntu Server, or are you using Lubuntu desktop as if it's a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have the Systemd journal at you disposal. Read up on the 'journalctl' command to learn all about it`man journalctl`. 
To view a list of boot logs from journald in a terminal:

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

Current boot:

```
journalctl -b 0
```

Previous boot:

```
journalctl -b 1
```

three boots ago:

```
journalctl -b 3
```

and so on.

Messages from two weeks ago:

```
journalctl --since="2020-2-15 9:30:00"
```

by unit(or service):

```
journalctl -u sddm.service
```

And much more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful and informative! I managed to solve my problem.